# objective c: passing a char argument to function crashes the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, singleton, char

I wrote a singleton called SomeValues where I initialize a foo NSMutableArray. I then tried to write a function SetBFSV to set the values of this array from different control views.

```
@interface SomeValues : NSObject {
NSMutableArray *foo;}
+ (SomeValues *) sharedInstance;

@implementation

...

- (void) SetBFSV:(char)lbl ToVal:(long)BFSvl{
NSNumber *ValueBFSvl = [NSNumber numberWithLong:BFSvl];
NSString *Strlbl = [[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat:@"%s",lbl];
[foo setValue:ValueBFSvl forKey:Strlbl];
}
```

I know that setValue requires a NS object for both the value and the key, but I cannot declare my function as

```
(void) SetBFSV:(NSString)lbl ToVal:(NSNumber)BFSvl
```

because it doesn't compile with the error: "Can not use an object as parameter to a method".

In one ControlView I wrote then this piece of code:

```
SomeValues *myBFSV = [SomeValues sharedInstance];
const unsigned char *Bar = (unsigned char *)[@"Label1" UTF8String];
NSLog(@"The string %s", Bar);
[myBFSV SetBFSV:Bar ToVal:2.5];
```

When compiling I get a warning on the last line:

warning: passing argument 1 of 'SetBFSV:ToVal:' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Which integer? I'm getting stupid looking around for it. When running I get the print out from the NSLog, but right afterwards the program obviously crashes with this error:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPlaceholderString stringWithFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e03280'

Clearly I'm passing something wrong to stringWithFormat but I cannot understand what.

Thanks for any help. Have a nice day!

/luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you can't use an object as a paramter:

```
(void) SetBFSV:(NSString)lbl ToVal:(NSNumber)BFSvl
```

You need to pass them as pointers, using the asterisk.

```
(void) SetBFSV:(NSString*)lbl ToVal:(NSNumber*)BFSvl
```

Furthermore, if you need to pass them as `(char)` and `(long)` your bit of code:

```
SomeValues *myBFSV = [SomeValues sharedInstance];
const unsigned char *Bar = (unsigned char *)[@"Label1" UTF8String];
NSLog(@"The string %s", Bar);
[myBFSV SetBFSV:Bar ToVal:2.5];  // in either case, this is a long.  why are you passing a double here?
```

Passes `*Bar` as a pointer.  You should really read up on the pointers and objects.  IF you need to pass them in as `(const char*)` and `(long)` do it like this:

```
- (void) SetBFSV:(const char*)lbl ToVal:(long)BFSvl{
NSNumber *ValueBFSvl = [NSNumber numberWithLong:BFSvl];
NSString *Strlbl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: lbl]; // your old code had a memory leak here.  you need to either create an autorelease object, or release it after adding to `foo`
[foo setValue:ValueBFSvl forKey:Strlbl];
}
```

My Recommendation is to do the following:

```
- (void) SetBFSV:(NSString*)key ToVal:(long)val{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithLong:val];
    [foo setValue:value forKey:key];
}
```

And call it like the following (from your example):

```
SomeValues *myBFSV = [SomeValues sharedInstance];
NSString *Bar = [NSString stringWithString:@"Label1"];// this may not be necessary...
NSLog(@"The string %@", Bar);
[myBFSV SetBFSV:Bar ToVal:25]; // don't pass a decimal for a (long)
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen,
you're right, I do need to read up some more about pointers and objects. Anyway, using (NSString *) did the trick. I will also use double instead of long and fix the memory leaking. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Possible problems with your code (unless you have typos in it):

1. `- (void) SetBFSV:(char)lbl ToVal:(long)BFSvl` function expects char as its 1st parameter but you pass it a char* - your 1st warning probably comes from here
2. stringWithFormat is a class method so your code should look either:

   ```
   NSString *Strlbl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s",lbl];
   [foo setValue:ValueBFSvl forKey:Strlbl]
   ```

   or

   ```
   NSString *Strlbl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",lbl];
   [foo setValue:ValueBFSvl forKey:Strlbl]
   ```

   since you try to use `-stringWithFormat` instead of `+stringWithFormat` you get a crash
3. If you pass char to a function then correct format specifier for it will be %c, not %s
4. You probably must release your Strlbl variable if you create it with alloc/init otherwise it will leak (but you must not release it if you use +stringWithFormat:)