# How to set up an NSMutableArray to be accessed from different tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, nsmutablearray

I have an app with a tab bar. Each tab has its own view controller. I also have a mutable array that each tab view controller should be able to access (get the ith element, add a new element, delete an element, etc). Right now, I'm doing an ugly hack, which is passing the array around as I change tabs with using things like this in the viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear methods:

```
[[[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Please can someone enlighten me as to the correct way to do this? I have a feeling I should just keep the array in my appdelegate, but I'm not sure how to access it from the other view controllers if I do that.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm facing a similar issue. After looking around I decided for a singleton which declares the NSMutableArray in its @interface, and then is shared between all the viewControllers.
I started from [this page](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/05/the-death-of-global-variables/) for the general shape. I'm then passing around calls to set up the values of the array. I'm not still 100% done (see [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016504/objective-c-passing-a-char-argument-to-function-crashes-the-app)) but I think this should be the way. Any other ideas are most than welcome!
Have a nice day!
/Luca